# pivot table with relationships in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in excel containing main contracts and a different table containing amendments to those contracts. In the amendment table there is a column that lists the main contract ID from the main contract table for each amendment. I have created a relationship between these two columns in power pivot. Now I have inserted a pivot table with the main contract ID from the main contracts table in the filter and the amendment ID from the amendments table in the row.

Now I thought that I would be able to select a main contract ID in the filter and the pivot table would show me all of the amendments associated with this main contract. The pivot table however just keeps displaying all of the amendments. Does someone have any idea what could be going wrong? Theoretically this should work right?

Comment: Welcome to Super User,, pleases [edit] you post & add some sample data, also the expected output.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about the data source? Based on your description, not easy to create a chart of your requirement.